# ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.time.temporal.Temporal

Tags: java, date, localdate, temporal

I am trying to work out the number of days between two dates. I am getting an error when I run the code: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.time.temporal.Temporal

Here is my code:

```
ServiceJpaController serController = new ServiceJpaController(emf);
    List<Service> serviceList = serController.findServiceEntities();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("Today date: "+ today); 
    for(Service service:serviceList){
        Date lastServiced = service.getDateOfService();
        System.out.println("Serviced date: "+ lastServiced); 
        long daysBetween = Duration.between(lastServiced.toInstant(), today).toDays();
        if(daysBetween >= 90){
            jTxtAreaServiceDate.append(service.toString());
        }}
```

The print statements were added just to check if the variables contained the dates, which they do.
The output window showed:

```
Today date: 2022-08-03

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.time.temporal.Temporal

Serviced date: Sun May 08 00:00:00 BST 2022
```

I've had a look for a solution but so far have been unable to find anything. If anyone could explain what the error means and how I could go about solving my problem I would be most grateful.

Comment: Edit your question and show the entire stack trace of the exception.  Then tell us which line the exception occurred at.

Comment: While the question is clear enough since the code presented cannot work correctly, I also cannot see how it could throw the exact exception you are mentioning. Probably you played around with versions of your code and ended up presenting one version of the code and the exception from a different version. A clear [mre] with the exact exception observed from the code presented would still be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do is to see if you can get `LocalDate` for the code
`Date lastServiced = service.getDateOfService();` which means returning `LocalDate` from method `service.getDateOfService();`

Sometimes it is probably not in your control.
Therefore you can try the next best solution, which is to convert Util.Date to a LocalDate.
You can use the below code for that.

```
LocalDate lastServiceLocalDate = lastServiced.toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate();
```

Now you have both `LocalDate` so you can use the below code to get days between

```
long daysBetween = DAYS.between(lastServiceLocalDate, today);
```

Comment: I had to add ChronoUnit before Days.between to get it to work, but it seems to be working as intended now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dan The answerer probably did an `import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;` to allow the syntax presented. In most cases I would probably solve it the same way you did, by putting `ChronoUnit.` in front of `DAYS` in the last code line.

Answer (score 0):

The `Duration.between()` takes two `Temporal` objects and returns days between as a `long`. Unfortunately, `Date` is not a `Temporal` type object.

Therefore, you need to convert `Date` into `LocalDate`. I think following code will work.

```
ServiceJpaController serController = new ServiceJpaController(emf);
    List<Service> serviceList = serController.findServiceEntities();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("Today date: "+ today); 
    for(Service service:serviceList){
        Date lastServiced = service.getDateOfService();
        System.out.println("Serviced date: "+ lastServiced);
        long daysBetween = 
                Duration.between(       
                    lastServiced
                        .toInstant()
                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                        .toLocalDate(), 
                    today
                )
                .toDays();
        if(daysBetween >= 90){
            jTxtAreaServiceDate.append(service.toString());
        }}
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but (a) Assuming the intended time zone is the JVM’s current default time zone seems impractical, and (b) `Duration#toDays` counts chunks of 24-hours, with no regard for the calendar nor time zone rule changes.